# Enable service worker with playwright

Tags: python, chromium, playwright

I'm playing with telegram and playwright, and most of the time I'm getting a pop up that says that service worker is disabled. I have no idea how to turn it on. This is how I launch the browser:

```py
browser = await playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
context = await browser.new_context(storage_state='state.json')
page = await context.new_page()
await page.goto(chat_url1)
```